# Socket Status when network interface is down

Tags: sockets

If a socket is attached with a network interface, what will be the socket status when that network interface goes down. If the current network interface is down, is it possible to change the network interface which is still up.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What sort of socket? Define "down."

Answer (score 0):

Once a socket is bound to an interface, that's it. If the interface goes down, the socket goes down. There is no option to jump the socket to a different interface. You have to close the socket and create a new socket on the new interface.